# Is there always a point $(h,k)$ in a polynomial function $P(x)$ for which $P$ becomes odd or even by translating $(h,k)$ to $(0,0)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

I can see that this holds for constants, linear functions, quadratics, and cubics, because:

1. For constants, $P(x) = a_0$, translating $P$ from $(0, P(0))$ to $(0,0)$ makes it an even function. (Even without translation, the function is still even.)

\begin{align*}
    P(c) &= a_0 \\
    P(-c) &= a_0 \\
    \therefore P(c) &= P(-c)
\end{align*}

2. For linear functions, $P(x) = a_1x + a_0$, translating $P$ from $(0,P(0))$ to $P(0,0)$ makes it an odd function. To see why, let $Q(x) = P(x) - a_0$. Now,
   \begin{align*}
       Q(x) &= P(x) - a_0 \\
       Q(x) &= a_1x + a_0 - a_0 \\
       Q(x) &= a_1x \\\\
       Q(-x) &= a_1(-x) \\
       Q(-x) &= -(a_1x) \\
       Q(-x) &= -Q(x)
   \end{align*}
3. For quadratic functions, $P(x) = a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$, translating $P$ from $\left(-\frac{a_1}{2a_2}, P\left(-\frac{a_1}{2a_2}\right)\right)$ to $(0,0)$ makes it an even function.

*Proof*. Let $\displaystyle  Q(x) = P\left(x - \frac{a_1}{2a_2}\right) - P\left(-\frac{a_1}{2a_2}\right)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
    Q(x) &= P\left(x - \frac{a_1}{2a_2}\right) - P\left(-\frac{a_1}{2a_2}\right) \\
    Q(x) &= a_2\left(x - \frac{a_1}{2a_2}\right)^{2} + a_1\left(x - \frac{a_1}{2a_2}\right) + a_0 - \frac{4a_2a_0 - a_1^2}{4a_2} \\
    Q(x) &= a_2\left(x^2 - \frac{a_1x}{a_2} + \frac{a_1^2}{4a_2^2}\right) + a_1\left(x - \frac{a_1}{2a_2}\right) + a_0 - \frac{4a_2a_0 - a_1^2}{4a_2} \\
    Q(x) &= a_2x^2 - a_1x + \frac{a_1^2}{4a_2} + a_1x - \frac{a_1^2}{2a_2} + a_0 - \frac{4a_2a_0 - a_1^2}{4a_2} \\
    Q(x) &= a_2x^2 + \frac{4a_2a_0 - a_1^2}{4a_2} - \frac{4a_2a_0 - a_1^2}{4a_2} \\
    Q(x) &= a_2x^2 \\\\
    Q(-x) &= a_2(-x)^2 \\
    Q(-x) &= a_2x^2 \\
    \therefore Q(-x) &= Q(x)
\end{align*}

4. For cubics, $P(x) = a_3x^3 + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$, translating $P$ from $\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}, P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)\right)$ to $0,0$ makes it an odd function.

*Proof*. Let $\displaystyle Q(x) = P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) - P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)$. Solving for $\displaystyle P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)$,
\begin{align*}
    P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= a_3\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)^3 + a_2\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)^2 + a_1\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) + a_0 \\
    P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= a_3\left(-\frac{a_2^3}{27a_3^3}\right) + a_2\left(\frac{a_2^2}{9a_3^2}\right) + a_1\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) + a_0 \\
    P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= -\frac{a_2^3}{27a_3^3} + \frac{a_2^3}{9a_3^2} - \frac{a_2a_1}{3a_3} + a_0
\end{align*}

Now, solving for $\displaystyle P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)$,
\begin{align*}
    P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= a_3\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)^3 + a_2\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right)^2 + a_1\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) + a_0 \\
    P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= a_3\left(x_3 - \frac{a_2x^2}{a_3} + \frac{a_2^2x}{3a_3^2} - \frac{a_2^3}{27a_3^3}\right) + a_2\left(x^2 - \frac{2a_2x}{3a_3} + \frac{a_2^2}{9a_3^2}\right) + a_1\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) + a_0 \\
    P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= a_3x^3 - a_2x^2 + \frac{a_2^2x}{3a_3} - \frac{a_2^3}{27a_3^2} + a_2x^2 - \frac{2a_2^2x}{3a_3} + \frac{a_2^3}{9a_3^2} + a_1x - \frac{a_2a_1}{3a_3} + a_0 \\
    P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= a_3x^3 + \frac{a_2^2x}{3a_3} - \frac{2a_2^2x}{3a_3} + a_1x - \frac{a_2^2}{27a_3^3} + \frac{a_2^3}{9a_3^2} - \frac{a_2a_1}{3a_3} + a_0 \\
    P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= a_3x^3 + \left(a_1 - \frac{a_2^2}{3a^3}\right)x + P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) 
\end{align*}

Solving for $Q(x)$,
\begin{align*}
    P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) &= a_3x^3 + \left(a_1 - \frac{a_2^2}{3a^3}\right)x + P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) \\
    Q(x) &= P\left(x - \frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) - P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) \\
    Q(x) &= a_3x^3 + \left(a_1 - \frac{a_2^2}{3a^3}\right)x + P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) - P\left(-\frac{a_2}{3a_3}\right) \\
    Q(x) &= a_3x^3 + \left(a_1 - \frac{a_2^2}{3a^3}\right)x \\\\
    Q(-x) &= a_3(-x)^3 + \left(a_1 - \frac{a_2^2}{3a^3}\right)(-x) \\
    Q(-x) &= -a_3x^3 - \left(a_1 - \frac{a_2^2}{3a^3}\right)x \\
    Q(-x) &= -\left(a_3x^3 + \left(a_1 - \frac{a_2^2}{3a^3}\right)x\right) \\
    Q(-x) &= -Q(x)
\end{align*}

---

I don't know if there is one for quartics, quintics, and for a general $n$. Can someone help fill the gap?

Comment: If we want to make a polynomial of lets say odd degree $n$ odd we would need to make all coefficients of even powers of $x$ zero. This will be $(n+1)/2$ equations but we only have $2$ variables ($x$ shift and $y$ shift), so this probably doesn't work in general for polynomials of degree $>3$. Indeed take e.g. $x^4+x$ (ok in this example we actually have only two equations and it still isn't possible to make this polynomial even by $x$/$y$-shifts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $p(x) = x^4+x$ for a counterexample.

Comment: Is there a way to prove the nonexistence of such polynomials? There may be one for an arbitrary $n$.